# Display calculated result in edit mode of standard pagelayout

Tags: formula-field

I have a requirement i need to do some calculation and display the value in edit mode of standard pagelayout. Can some one give some suggestion how i can do that. User wants to see the result in edit mode itself.

Comment: are you open to VF? If not, this can't be done

Comment: @cropredy: I suggested that to the client but they are not open to VF.

Comment: Try to create a visual force page and you can use that page in standard layout. May it works for  you @Tamil

Answer (score 4):

A standard edit page will only show fields that are editable. Hence, formula fields are not going to be displayed - and anyway, the formula field wouldn't be calculated until the Save action anyway -- and then would appear on the standard detail page.

Without VF, this can't be done. Tell your client that the standard point-and-click SFDC offers tremendous productivity savings but has some limitations, this being one.

With VF, you can use client side logic (Javascript) to manipulate data based on DOM events and present running calculations as fields are entered